# Remove Laravel job failing limit

Tags: laravel

After failing a queue job more than 3 times, This error happens:
`App\Jobs\UpdateProviderPrices has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out.`
Also Laravel queue do not allow other jobs to run due to that error.

How should i completely remove the limit of failing queue job ? I saw another topic that said by increasing `retry_after`, the error will be solved, but in my case it will not, because the queue may fail a million time, because i dispatch it every minute.

Also i have to mention that i use this job for plural processing, Is there any alternative ?

Comment: try specifying   public $tries = 3; in job

Comment: What is the said time limit of the job you are trying to process and how long does that job run?

Comment: If `--tries=0` is provided to the `queue:work` command, the job will retried indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

When a job takes longer than the configured maximum execution time or when it exceeds the maximum number of allowed retries than laravel throws error.

> Increase the job timeout: You can increase the maximum execution time of your job by setting the timeout property on your job class to a higher value
>
> Increase the maximum number of job attempts:You can increase the maximum number of times a job can be attempted by setting the tries property on your job class to a higher value.